# Is it possible to create a custom widget in Amazon Webstore?

Tags: templates, webstore

I need to create a form, which on submission, filters search results based on certain keywords.

The keywords I'm working with a year, make, model (it's a car part site).  If I use Amazon's webstore search function. Make and Model are parameters that are able to be used because most of the products have make and model in the product name, which isn't really the most efficient to say the least.

I need to be able to query the product database, but it's just not how Amazon Webstore, I assume.

Does anybody have an example of this that I can look at?  Does anyone develop custom templates in Amazon Webstore so I can ask questions?

Answer (score 1):

Start at the [Amazon Webstore Forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/amazonwebstore) with dedicated staff, documentation and help folks, and more solutions.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  I'll take a look there.  I have not yet seen this site.